# fonts changed when using tight_layout with python

Tags: python, matplotlib

just to show what i mean, I have used the following code

```
import math

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
for xi in range(1, 10):
  x.append(xi)
  y.append(math.sin(xi))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel("x", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("y", fontsize=14)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The first pic is without tight_layout(), while the 2nd is with tight_layout(). See how the font size and possibly the type has changed completely. Can I use tight_layout() without changing the font properties?

[image: This is without tight_layout]
[image: This is with tight_layout]

Comment: I think the typescript is unchanged. But I agree the size is different, and possibly - like the frame - the labels have been distorted.

Comment: My environment is matplotlib 3.5.1, and the graph is the same regardless of whether I have a tight layout or not.

Comment: What environment are you using to create the plots? I'm curious about your OS, Matplotlib version. Also would you be able to post the Matplotlib backend such as Qt5Agg.. I'm curious to see if some of these things make a difference.